# Powershell Create/check folder copy data with logging

Tags: powershell

Hi all I have this code below, it is a bit of a mash up at the moment. 
Basically, I need a function that will grab the name of Source and copies it to Destination, it will grab the name of the folder from Source and create it on Destination if it does not exist, then copies all files and folder in to it. Plus with logging on each step. The below works, but when I run it again to test to see if it exist it copies it again under the folder so duplicates it. How do I get it to overwrite? also need to streamline the code, i think its a bit much for a simple task.

EDIT - I have changed the MoveData function, just trying to get the progress bar bit working for each file.

Thanks in advance.

```
#Copy Users Data to Storage
Function MoveData ($Src, $Dest) {

$counter = 1
get-childItem $FolderSource -filter *.* | foreach-object {
# here you can put your pre-copy tests...

$status = "Copy files {0} on {1}" -f $counter,$foldersource.Count
Write-Progress -Activity "Copy data" $status -PercentComplete ($counter)

copy-item $_.FullName -destination $NewFolder -errorAction SilentlyContinue -errorVariable errors -force -Recurse
foreach($error in $errors)
{
if ($error.Exception -ne $null)
{
write-host -foregroundColor Red "Exception: $($error.Exception)"
}
write-host -foregroundColor Red "Error: An error occured during copy operation."
}
}
$counter++
}#End Function
```

Comment: Please read this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Changed it to just the MoveData Function.

Comment: "but when I run it again to test to see if it exist" Where are you doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I do not have a good way to capture errors in this script, but you could probably use a Try{}/Catch{} thing to get the errors. What this does do is copy files, and display a progress bar with file count. It also checks the source folder and destination folder against each other. If the last folder in the source and the last folder in the dest are the same it checks to see if the dest exists, if not it creates it. If they are different it checks to see if the last folder in the source exists in the destination, and if not it creates it and sets the destination to that. It also includes a switch `-Exact` in case you want it to copy to the destination folder exactly as it was given, and it has a -Force option, that makes it overwrite files if they already exist.

```
Function Copy-Files{
Param(
    [Parameter(Position=0)]$Source = $(Throw "You must specify the source path."),
    [Parameter(Position=1)]$Dest = $(Throw "You must specify the destination path."),
    [switch]$Exact = $False,
    [switch]$Force = $False
)
    Begin{
        $Source = Resolve-Path $Source
        Switch($Source){
            {!$Exact -and !((Split-Path $Source -Leaf) -ieq (Split-Path $dest -Leaf)) -and !(Test-Path "$dest\$(Split-Path $Source -Leaf)")}{New-Item (Join-Path $dest (Split-Path $Source -Leaf)) -ItemType Directory|Out-Null;$dest = Join-Path $dest (Split-Path $Source -Leaf)}
            {$Exact -and !(Test-Path $Dest)}{New-Item -path $dest -ItemType Directory}
            {!$Exact -and !((Split-Path $Source -Leaf) -ieq (Split-Path $dest -Leaf)) -and (Test-Path "$dest\$(Split-Path $Source -Leaf)")}{$dest = Join-Path $dest (Split-Path $Source -Leaf)}
        }
        $Files = GCI $Source -Recurse
        $i = 0
    }
    Process{
        ForEach($File in $Files){
            $i++
            If($File.PSIsContainer -and !(Test-Path ($File.fullname -replace [RegEx]::Escape($Source),"$Dest"))){New-Item ($File.FullName -replace [RegEx]::Escape($Source),"$Dest") -ItemType Directory|Out-Null}ElseIf(!$File.PSIsContainer){
                Write-Progress -Activity ("Copying Files ({0} of {1})" -f $i, $files.Count) -PercentComplete (($i/$files.count)*100)
                If($Force){
                    Copy-Item -path $File.fullname -Destination ($File.fullname -replace [RegEx]::Escape($Source),"$Dest") -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -force
                }else{
                    Copy-Item -path $File.fullname -Destination ($File.fullname -replace [RegEx]::Escape($Source),"$Dest") -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think in your case you would do `Copy-Files "c:\users\someguy\documents" "z:\userbackups" -force` or something along those lines.

**Edit:** Ok, the duplicate sub-folder issue is fixed now. It was copying items, but since a folder's FileInfo object's FullName property actually contains the name of the folder itself when the folder was copied it caused a duplicate (though empty) copy of itself in the destination. The updated function checks to see if the item being copied is a folder, and if so it checks if that folder exists in the destination and creates it if it doesn't. If it does exist it quietly moves on. The only things actually copied are files, folders are really checked for existence in the destination and created as needed instead of copying them.

Comment: Hi MadTechnician, thank you for your help it works great...one thing, if I run it once it works, then run it again on the same folders, it creates another folder under the sub folder..so it would be UserA\SubFolderA\SubFolderA instead of overwriting it...any idea?

Comment: Uuuhhh... that seems strange. Give me a minute to look and see if I can replicate that.

Comment: Ta, i had the same issue on other scripts, can couldnt figure it out.

Comment: I got it... Updated answer with explanation of what was happening.

Comment: Awesome work my friend, thank you. Top work! Need to get my powershell hat on now.

Comment: If my answer resolved your question please mark it as accepted so the question is not left as technically 'unanswered' and it can be used to help future users searching for help.

Comment: Will do, i updated my last comment about the 2000 files transfer saying it copied by no files was there.

Comment: Must be a limitation on it, it can copy less 100kb ok, but 150mb it doesnt. nothing gets copied, even though the progress bar says it's done it.

Comment: It works for me. Perhaps it is a network issue on your end where the file copy fails due to network latency? I just did a folder with 288 items, 3 at least were over 150MB. That was locally though.